# webrtc connection between server to browser

Tags: node.js, browser, ffmpeg, webrtc

I want to connect webrtc peer connection between node js server and browser. I will be sending the video stream to server using ffmpeg. Since connection will establish between server and client, client will recieve the stream to display the stream. Note: My actual situation is robot will be streaming the video to browser.

Can any one suggest how can i solve this scenario.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? And have you run into any issues?

Comment: Hi Inoguier, I am trying to figure out the library which can help me on this. gone though wrtc nodejs library but it doesn't help me. Any suggestion is helpful